# Pass multiple strings to Angular attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to build an Angular attribute directive which accepts a 'prefix' and 'state' and adds a class to the element based on these values. The problem I'm running into is that the attribute seems to only accept a string. Below I am passing 'prefix' to the function within my directive and getting ahold of state in a very roundabout way. Is there a way to pass both 'prefix' and 'state' to this attribute directive?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app')
    .directive('playerState', playerStateDirective)
  ;

  playerStateDirective.$inject = [];

  function playerStateDirective() {
    var postLink = function(scope, iElem, iAttrs) {
      function setClass(prefix) {
        var optionalTrailingDash = /(-)?$/;

        prefix = String(prefix || '').replace(optionalTrailingDash, '-');
        var state = scope.$parent.vm.player.player_state;

        var map = {
          active: prefix === 'bg-' ? 'info' : 'primary',
          closed: 'danger'
        };

        var playerStateClass = prefix.concat(map[state] || 'default');
        iElem.addClass(playerStateClass);
      };

      iAttrs.$observe('playerState', setClass);
    };

    return {
      link: postLink,
      restrict: 'A'
    };
  }
})();
```

Directive use:

```
<a player-state="text" ng-href="/players/{{vm.player.id}}">{{vm.player.email}}</a>
```

Comment: You should look into isolate scope

Comment: why dont you pass two attributes? `<mydirective first="first one" second="second one">`  you should be able to get them in the directive like `iAttrs.first, iAttrs.second`

Comment: it's a bit unclear as to what you're trying to do, and what's not working. Although @Akis shows an element directive, you can use multiple attributes, even with an attribute directive, by simply including them on the same element `<a player-state="text" player-prefix="joe" `...